# onbeforeunload not working after downloading attachment

Tags: javascript

I have a jsp page home.jsp, which is broken into two frames Header and Content.
In my content frame, I have a link which calls a servlet like this

```
<a href="downloadAttach">download</a>
```

The JavaScript function dowloadAttach has this below line:

```
window.location="RetrieveFile.display";
```

RetrieveFile is a servlet, which takes a document from a shared location and writes it to ouputstream, so that i get an option to save/cancel/open the attachment

In addition, all pages in content frame has the below line of code, to ensure that the page is not cached in browser:

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){window.location.replace("<%= request.getcontextPath()%>/home.jsp")}
```

In addition I have the below script in my home.jsp, to ensure that a warning message is displayed whenever, the home.jsp is unloaded. the script is like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){return "sure you want to go away"};
```

Now suppose I am in google and then move to home.jsp, and then click the download attachment link. The attachment is downloaded correctly. After that, i do any action on the jsp which causes the page to refresh, like submit a form or close a form and then press browser back, my home.jsp unloads and i am taken to google, and the pop up message does not shows. The message comes, if i perfom the exact same steps nd did a browser refresh or close. I have also tried setting the headers in the servlet for cache-control, but doesnt make any difference. I am using ie8

Comment: typo in `window.onbeforeunload=fucntion()`

Comment: updated... :)...but that was not the issue!!!

Comment: @user1850675 I think I have a similar issue, after I load a window on top of my main page to get some detail, then close this the event onbeforeunload no longer fires on the main page.  Did you solve this in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I found this Jquery works for my similar problem:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { 
 return "sure you want to go away";
});
```